# Log Error Using The Grid Pluging on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im creating a new website, and installed The Grid pluging because its mostly the best pluging for grid in wordpress, but when im going to use it im getting this console error, its the first time im getting this error have more than 10 pages with it.

This is the pluging: https://codecanyon.net/item/the-grid-responsive-wordpress-grid-plugin/13306812

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zonj.jpg

Any advice for whats going on

Its a fresh wordpress installation
Using CESIS THEME (Iñve used before this theme with the pluging, several websites)
Using last version of wordpress.
Tried disabling all my pluging except the grid.

I've tried several things.

If can help would appreciate

Thanks
Rodrigo Zuluaga

```
LOG ERROR
slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11 Uncaught TypeError: a.toFixed is not a function
    at a.<computed>.<computed>._calculateNewMax (slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
    at a.<computed>.<computed>._calculateNewMax (widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
    at a.<computed>.<computed>._create (slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
    at a.<computed>.<computed>._create (widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
    at a.<computed>.<computed>._createWidget (widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
    at new a.<computed>.<computed> (widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
    at HTMLSpanElement.<anonymous> (widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
    at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.a.fn.<computed> [as slider] (widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11)
_calculateNewMax    @   slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @   widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
_create @   slider.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @   widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
_createWidget   @   widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
a.<computed>.<computed> @   widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @   widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
each    @   load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2
each    @   load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2
a.fn.<computed> @   widget.min.js?ver=1.11.4:11
(anonymous) @   tomb.js?ver=1.0:579
each    @   load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2
each    @   load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2
init    @   tomb.js?ver=1.0:575
init    @   tomb.js?ver=1.0:42
(anonymous) @   tomb.js?ver=1.0:18
i   @   load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2
fireWith    @   load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2
ready   @   load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2
J   @   load-scripts.php?c=0…lupload&ver=5.2.4:2

2wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.4:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.4:1)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3)
    at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3)
    at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:8)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3)
    at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.4:1)
(anonymous) @ wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.4:1
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3
r.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3
trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3
a.event.trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:8
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3
each @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:2
each @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:2
trigger @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3
(anonymous) @ heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.4:1
i @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:2
fireWith @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:2
x @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:4
c @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:4
ajax @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:4
j @ heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.4:1
k @ heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.4:1
m @ heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.4:1
(anonymous) @ heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.4:1
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3
r.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,underscore,shortcode,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.4:3
```

Comment: Could you paste the errors here instead of a screenshot?

Comment: Posted the errors @disinfor